# Ways to limit Phaser3 update rate?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

In my Phaser3 game there is a global gameTick variable that is incremented every update. I am using this to spawn in enemies in my game every 100th update.

Here is a simplifed example of what is going on in my scene class:

```js
update () {
    global.gameTick++;

    if (global.gameTick % 100 === 0) {
        this.spawnAlien();
    }
}
```

This works fine but as soon as a user plays the game on a monitor with a refresh rate >60hz the update timing breaks and causes the aliens to spawn more frequently.

I have checked `this.physics.world.fps` and it is 60. I can also modify `this.physics.world.timescale` but then I would have to do a giant switch statement for every refresh rate.

Either I am missing an obvious solution or my `global.gameTick` method is not an effective way to accomplish this task.

This is what I have in my config so far

```js
let config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    scale: {
        parent: "game",
        mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
        width: 1900,
        height: 600,
    },
    physics: {
        default: "arcade",
        arcade: {
            debug: true,
            fps: 60 // doesn't fix update frequency
        },
        fps: { // not sure if this is even doing anything
            max: 60,
            min: 20,
            target: 60,
        }
    },
    pixelArt: true,
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit the update rate, use the following method.

```js
// The time and delta variables are passed to `update()` by Phaser
update(time, delta) {
    this.frameTime += delta

    if (this.frameTime > 16.5) {  
        this.frameTime = 0;
        g.gameTick++;
        // Code that relies on a consistent 60hz update
    }
}
```

This accumulates the miiliseconds between the last frame and the current frame. It only runs the `update()` code if there has been 16.5ms of delay.

The example above works for 60fps, but if you want to limit the FPS to a different value use the formula: `delay = 1000/fps`.

Comment: What is g in g.gameTick++??

Comment: @DarthVader It’s just an abbreviation of `global.gametick` from the question

Answer (score 4):

You can also set the following property in your game's config object:

```
fps: {
  target: 24,
  forceSetTimeOut: true
},
```

Source: https://phaser.discourse.group/t/how-to-limit-fps-with-phaser-3/275/14?u=saricden